# Cannot access NGC folder as admin

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1709

I am unable to login to my PC using my PIN.  The recommended fix is to clear the contents of the NGC folder.  Unfortunately, I cannot access it.

> **Command prompt without admin privileges:**
>
> ```
> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService
> λ cd appdata
> Access is denied.
> ```

> **With admin privileges:**
>
> ```
> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService
> λ cd appdata
>
> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData
> λ cd local
>
> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local
> λ cd microsoft
>
> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft
> λ cd ngc
> Access is denied.
> ```

It literally doesn't even show up in Windows Explorer, even with hidden and system files visible.

What might cause this? How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to do some security changes to the folders. Please follow this guide: https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-pin-not-working-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the directory Ngc select Properties, then goto Security tab, change permissions owner to your local admin user, then apply.

Now you are able to delete the folder.